# SSH slow Cassandra cluster

Tags: linux, ssh, cassandra, centos

We had a strange issue that we don't know where to look for answer. We are using Cassandra (2.0.10) cluster with 4 nodes. The OS is using CentOS 6.4. We are monitoring those Dell machines using rsh command every minute by dumping their ps and top list. Once a while (about 2 weeks to more than one month), we found rsh command return from one of the machines was very slow (more than 5 sec as compared to less than 1 sec) . At those moment, we noticed that it was very slow to putty to that specific machine as well, while it was fine with other nodes in the same cluster. On the problematic machine, even after we stopped cassandra service, things didn't improve. SSH and ps command still came back much slower than other machines. This didn't get improved until we rebooted the machine. This happened to two of the 4 machines used in the cluster. We looked at the message logs, hardware logs, cassandra logs and can't find the source of this issue. Has anybody experienced this? We love to hear any suggestions.

Comment: As a guess, this sounds like you may have swap enabled and the machines were swapping.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Yes, at present, there is a swap partition on the system and enabled.